# Self updating application in android

Tags: java, android, shell, kotlin, adb

I need to update my app silently without user interaction.

I use this code for the update app.

I use a root device. this [device](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/smart210) and android 4.0.3.

```
 public static void installNewApk() {

        String path = AppController.instance.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "app-release.apk";

        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "pm install -r " + path});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.out.println("no root");
        }
    }
```

but after running this code, I get this error and app not install.

```
 D/AudioHardware: AudioHardware pcm playback is exiting standby.
 D/AudioHardware: openPcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 0
 E/su: sudb - Opening database
 E/su: sudb - Database opened
 E/su: sudb - Database closed
 D/su: 10062 com.rasoul.test executing 0 pm install -r /data/data/com.rasoul.test/files/app-release.apk using shell /system/bin/sh : sh
 D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
 D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
 W/dalvikvm: Exception Ljava/lang/NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Ljava/lang/System;
 W/dalvikvm: Exception Ljava/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError; thrown while initializing Ljava/lang/ClassLoader$SystemClassLoader;
 W/dalvikvm: WARNING: system class loader is NULL (setting main ctxt)
 W/dalvikvm: Warning: tracked references remain post-initialization
 W/dalvikvm: MAIN reference table (0xe9be80) dump:
 W/dalvikvm:   Last 1 entries (of 1):
 E/dalvikvm: Class lookup Ljava/lang/Daemons; attempted with exception pending
 W/dalvikvm: Pending exception is:
 I/dalvikvm: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:125)
 I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 I/dalvikvm: Caused by:
 I/dalvikvm: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.createSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:100)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.access$000(ClassLoader.java:65)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.ClassLoader$SystemClassLoader.<clinit>(ClassLoader.java:81)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:125)
 I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 I/dalvikvm: Caused by:
 I/dalvikvm: java.lang.NullPointerException:
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:365)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.System.initSystemProperties(System.java:286)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.System.getProperties(System.java:260)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:425)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:406)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.System.<clinit>(System.java:90)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.createSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:100)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.access$000(ClassLoader.java:65)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.ClassLoader$SystemClassLoader.<clinit>(ClassLoader.java:81)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:125)
 I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 I/dalvikvm: DALVIK THREADS:
 I/dalvikvm: (mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)
 I/dalvikvm: "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
 I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a40460 self=0xe9b828
 I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=6938 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074472072
 I/dalvikvm:   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=12 stm=3 core=0
 I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/dalvikvm: VM aborting
 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)
 I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
 I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/full_mini210/mini210:4.0.3/IML74K/eng.root.20150408.135557:eng/test-keys'
 I/DEBUG: pid: 6938, tid: 6938  >>> app_process <<<
 I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d
 I/DEBUG:  r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 400ac1ac  r3 00000000
 I/DEBUG:  r4 deadd00d  r5 408c8c58  r6 0000020c  r7 402220a8
 I/DEBUG:  r8 00000000  r9 408c3f90  10 408a6665  fp 00000000
 I/DEBUG:  ip 408c4070  sp bea06110  lr 40861807  pc 40861806  cpsr 60000030
 I/DEBUG:  d0  74726f6261204d56  d1  726174536576696e
 I/DEBUG:  d2  7953247265646175  d3  73616c436d65746c
 I/DEBUG:  d4  4bd752184bd751e0  d5  4bd752884bd75250
 I/DEBUG:  d6  4bd752f84bd752c0  d7  4bd753684bd75330
 I/DEBUG:  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
 I/DEBUG:  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
 I/DEBUG:  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
 I/DEBUG:  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
 I/DEBUG:  d16 0000000000000000  d17 3f50624dd2f1a9fc
 I/DEBUG:  d18 41b68fb7a9000000  d19 0000000000000000
 I/DEBUG:  d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
 I/DEBUG:  d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
 I/DEBUG:  d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
 I/DEBUG:  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
 I/DEBUG:  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
 I/DEBUG:  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
 I/DEBUG:  scr 60000010
 I/DEBUG:          #00  pc 00050806  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort)
 I/DEBUG:          #01  pc 00075ae4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/DEBUG:          #02  pc 00076282  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z24dvmFindSystemClassNoInitPKc)
 I/DEBUG:          #03  pc 00076ac2  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z18dvmFindSystemClassPKc)
 I/DEBUG:          #04  pc 0006019e  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z19dvmGcStartupClassesv)
 I/DEBUG:          #05  pc 00052712  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z10dvmStartupiPKPKcbP7_JNIEnv)
 I/DEBUG:          #06  pc 00053e0a  /system/lib/libdvm.so (JNI_CreateJavaVM)
 I/DEBUG:          #07  pc 000450e2  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime7startVmEPP7_JavaVMPP7_JNIEnv)
 I/DEBUG:          #08  pc 000454c4  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime5startEPKcS2_)
 I/DEBUG:          #09  pc 00008f0a  /system/bin/app_process
 I/DEBUG:          #10  pc 000164e4  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init)
 I/DEBUG: code around pc:
 I/DEBUG: 408617e4 34b4f8d3 ee98f7cd 26001e73 2f01f813  ...4....s..&.../
 I/DEBUG: 408617f4 42abb152 d0074416 4798e7f8 f7ff4c0a  R..B.D.....G.L..
 I/DEBUG: 40861804 7026ffa7 ee8ef7cd 2006490c 44794a0c  ..&p.....I. .JyD
 I/DEBUG: 40861814 f7cd447a 2000ed44 ee06f7cd 58e54b05  zD..D.. .....K.X
 I/DEBUG: 40861824 2b006c6b e7e9d1e9 deadd00d 000627d4  kl.+.........'..
 I/DEBUG: code around lr:
 I/DEBUG: 408617e4 34b4f8d3 ee98f7cd 26001e73 2f01f813  ...4....s..&.../
 I/DEBUG: 408617f4 42abb152 d0074416 4798e7f8 f7ff4c0a  R..B.D.....G.L..
 I/DEBUG: 40861804 7026ffa7 ee8ef7cd 2006490c 44794a0c  ..&p.....I. .JyD
 I/DEBUG: 40861814 f7cd447a 2000ed44 ee06f7cd 58e54b05  zD..D.. .....K.X
 I/DEBUG: 40861824 2b006c6b e7e9d1e9 deadd00d 000627d4  kl.+.........'..
 I/DEBUG: memory map around addr deadd00d:
 I/DEBUG: be9e6000-bea07000 [stack]
 I/DEBUG: (no map for address)
 I/DEBUG: ffff0000-ffff1000 [vectors]
 I/DEBUG: stack:
 I/DEBUG:     bea060d0  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea060d4  4007cce7  /system/lib/libc.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea060d8  400a6720  /system/lib/libc.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea060dc  400a66b0  /system/lib/libc.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea060e0  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea060e4  4007df01  /system/lib/libc.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea060e8  400a655c  /system/lib/libc.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea060ec  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea060f0  0000020c
 I/DEBUG:     bea060f4  402220a8  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea060f8  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea060fc  4007cd17  /system/lib/libc.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea06100  408c3f90  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea06104  bea06313  [stack]
 I/DEBUG:     bea06108  df0027ad
 I/DEBUG:     bea0610c  00000000
 I/DEBUG: #00 bea06110  bea062a4  [stack]
 I/DEBUG:     bea06114  6c756e28
 I/DEBUG:     bea06118  0000296c
 I/DEBUG:     bea0611c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06120  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06124  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06128  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0612c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06130  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06134  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06138  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0613c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06140  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06144  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06148  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0614c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06150  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06154  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06158  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0615c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06160  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06164  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06168  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0616c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06170  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06174  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06178  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0617c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06180  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06184  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06188  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0618c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06190  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06194  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06198  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0619c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061a0  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061a4  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061a8  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061ac  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061b0  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061b4  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061b8  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061bc  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061c0  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061c4  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061c8  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061cc  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061d0  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061d4  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061d8  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061dc  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061e0  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061e4  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061e8  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061ec  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061f0  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061f4  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061f8  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea061fc  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06200  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06204  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06208  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0620c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06210  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06214  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06218  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0621c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06220  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06224  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06228  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0622c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06230  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06234  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06238  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0623c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06240  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06244  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06248  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0624c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06250  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06254  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06258  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0625c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06260  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06264  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06268  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0626c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06270  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06274  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06278  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0627c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06280  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06284  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06288  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0628c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06290  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06294  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06298  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0629c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062a0  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062a4  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062a8  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062ac  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062b0  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062b4  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062b8  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062bc  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062c0  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062c4  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062c8  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062cc  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062d0  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062d4  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062d8  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062dc  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062e0  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062e4  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062e8  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062ec  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062f0  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062f4  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062f8  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea062fc  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06300  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06304  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06308  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0630c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06310  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06314  452d4875  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
 I/DEBUG:     bea06318  408a43eb  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea0631c  bea0651c  [stack]
 I/DEBUG:     bea06320  00e9b828  [heap]
 I/DEBUG:     bea06324  40886ae9  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/DEBUG: #01 bea06328  408c3f90  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea0632c  4086d5ff  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea06330  00000001
 I/DEBUG:     bea06334  4bd3afa8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
 I/DEBUG:     bea06338  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea0633c  bea06380  [stack]
 I/DEBUG:     bea06340  0000000c
 I/DEBUG:     bea06344  00e9b828  [heap]
 I/DEBUG:     bea06348  00e9bb94  [heap]
 I/DEBUG:     bea0634c  408ab2a4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea06350  0000001b
 I/DEBUG:     bea06354  400ab474
 I/DEBUG:     bea06358  0000200b
 I/DEBUG:     bea0635c  00e94000  [heap]
 I/DEBUG:     bea06360  00f1f2e0  [heap]
 I/DEBUG:     bea06364  00002000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06368  00e98d00  [heap]
 I/DEBUG:     bea0636c  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06370  408a6665  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea06374  400779dd  /system/lib/libc.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea06378  00e9b828  [heap]
 I/DEBUG:     bea0637c  40a40460  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
 I/DEBUG:     bea06380  00000000
 I/DEBUG:     bea06384  00e9b828  [heap]
 I/DEBUG:     bea06388  40a40530  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
 I/DEBUG:     bea0638c  00000001
 I/DEBUG:     bea06390  00000010
 I/DEBUG:     bea06394  408c3f90  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea06398  bea0651c  [stack]
 I/DEBUG:     bea0639c  00e9b828  [heap]
 I/DEBUG:     bea063a0  402220a8  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea063a4  00e98d00  [heap]
 I/DEBUG:     bea063a8  bea06494  [stack]
 I/DEBUG:     bea063ac  408a6665  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea063b0  408a66aa  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/DEBUG:     bea063b4  40887287  /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

Comment: How would you expect this to be possible? If the code is executed from your app (the app you're trying to update), it's like trying to cut off a branch on a tree while sitting on the same branch - it's just not possible.

Comment: @Darwind I use this code for other packageName, but this code doesn't work.

Comment: So this code is run from another application?

Comment: @Darwind yes, run from other application

Comment: @Darwind do you have a solver?

Comment: No, sorry I'm afraid not. It's difficult to say what the problem is. I'm wondering whether it could be an issue with missing permissions even though you're using `su`.